# Spoke Pattern Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Im not a math genius ... But im a good Programmer . A few days ago i heard about a spoke Pattern Algorithm . I wanna try to Programm an application, which Scans different text messages, compare them to each other and after that gives you an result if the Text was written by the same Person ... Is this possible ? And if it's possible, where can I find such an Algorithm? I already googled but didn't found one ... I could really need some help :)

Comment: This sounds less like an algorithm and more like application development.  You can certainly find references on the web about comparing word counts, etc. to provide a "metric" (measurement) of similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to research is Stylometry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry), the study and application of writing style to determine authorship.  This type of thing is definitely possible and has been implemented (http://www.philocomp.net/humanities/signature.htm).

You will face significant challenges though if you are trying to analyze text messages.

- People don't write text messages the same way they write longer messages.
- Text messages tend to be very short, i.e., there is very little data per message.
- There are so many conventions in text messages that they tend to be more conformed than speech or longer texts.
- Text messages are mobile communications and since text is limited the context is more uniform.  That is, there are probably lots of "where r u?" or "on my way" "can you get this at the store."